# IdentityServer4: invalid_client always returned

Tags: c#, token, identityserver4

I'm new to IdentityServer4 and I'm trying to understand how can I implement it with my website, so please be polite with me :D

I configured a client on Identity server and then I'm trying to request a token. I already double-checked the clientId, secret and scope, but I'm still having an "invalid_client" error. Maybe it's something I am missing in the Client configuration on Identity server?

That's my code.

```
        var serverClient = new HttpClient();

        var discoveryDocument = await serverClient.GetDiscoveryDocumentAsync(authServerURL);
        
        //discoveryDocument is ok!
        var tokenResponse = await serverClient.RequestClientCredentialsTokenAsync(
            new ClientCredentialsTokenRequest
            {
                Address = discoveryDocument.TokenEndpoint,
                ClientId = "myClient",
                ClientSecret = "mySecret",
                Scope = "openid",
            });

        if (tokenResponse.IsError)
        {
            //always true! error: invalid_client
            throw new Exception(tokenResponse.Error);
        }
```

--- EDIT: Client settings ---

I set up my client with [Skoruba IdentityServer UI](https://github.com/skoruba/IdentityServer4.Admin), duplicating the existing default one. Here my settings:

Client Name
[image: Client Name]

Basic settings (the secret is correct, I doublechecked it)
[image: Basic settings]

Token settings (Allowed CORS is from my local API instance and I even tried to leave it blank)
[image: Token settings (Allowed CORS is from my local instance and I even tried to leave it blank)]

Thanks.
Dario.

Comment: "*please be polite with me*" - its a good thing you said this, because we had pitch forks and broom handles at the ready

Comment: can you show the request you're sending?

Comment: also the full error string

Comment: I get a 400 - Bad Request, The json is: { "error" : "invalid_client"}

Comment: can you post a copy of your client definition in IdentityServer?

Comment: @ToreNestenius I edited my post, I set up the client with Skoruba UI, so let me know if you need other screenshots. Thanks.

Comment: After some tries, removing the Cors origin, i get an invalid_scope error message

Comment: Shouldn't your grant type be Code and not client credentials? Client credentials is usually an unattended access type and doesn't work the same way, since you cannot redirect to authorise client credentials.

Comment: It seems the problem was the Hash Type of the secret. I stored it with SHA512 instad of SHA256. There's a way to specify the SHA on sending ClientCredentialsTokenRequest?